# Docker Installation Fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Trying to get docker running for the first time on Ubuntu Linux. Followed the steps (as super user):

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install docker.io`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker.io is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up scx (1.6.3.326) ...
Failed to issue method call: Unit omid.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status omid.service' for details.
dpkg: error processing package scx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's strange because I have not used docker pkg before so not sure why this would give out an error. Trying to find some info on docker site, but no luck.

Any clues anyone?

Comment: The repo version will lag a fair bit behind anyway, so could you [try the official apt repo](https://blog.docker.com/2015/07/new-apt-and-yum-repos/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. I suggest you delete it and post on [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1):

`docker.io` is maintained by Ubuntu developers. Better use [official Docker distribution](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository). It's up-to-date and better supported.